# How do you automate enabling a service on a debian filesystem without booting into it?

Tags: linux, debian, deployment, service, systemd

I want to have a custom service that I've placed into /lib/systemd/system start at boot, but th eonly way I know how at the moment is to run

```
systemctl enable myservice.service
```

but I would like to be able to do this without booting into the actual file system so that I can automate the deployment of this configuration.

Comment: I assume that you have your Debian filesystem mounted somewhere?  Can you simply run `chroot /mountpoint systemctl enable myservice.service`?

Comment: Or rather `systemd-nspawn -b -D /mountpoint` instead of `chroot` – but in this case symlinking will be sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What `systemctl enable` does is creates a symlink for the service you specify from the `/lib/systemd/system` folder to `/etc/systemd/multi-user.target.wants`, so you can simply do:

`ln -s '/lib/systemd/system/myservice.service' '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/myservice.service'`